# Platform for building a FAQ answering chatbot on

Tags: chatbot, platform

I am trying to build a chatbot that answers FAQ from customers at the company I worked for. I have played around with Dialogflow and ManyChat, but I am not really satisfied with these platforms so far. Do you have any recommendations for platforms that can be used to build a chatbot on that answers questions from customers?

I am looking for a platform that provides easy semantic interpretation and implementation to a website and Facebook Messenger, perferably with multi language support.

Does anyone with experience have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to choose **.net framework** because it has large number of libraries and easy to use. And i advise you to create **`web service`** or **`web Api`** Choose C# for code in **.net framework** so you will be able to use your bot service any where you want. It has a lot of help on internet and many nuget packages.

If you choose this framework you will be able to integrate your bot in websites, Mobile and infact anywhere you want . 
**You can check this out** [Microsoft Link for Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308359/how-to-write-a-simple-web-service-by-using-visual-c--net)